# Reversed if check

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a huge list of checks that checks for example if integer is 4 or 10, if it is 4 it changes this int to 10 and Vice versa so my if check would be something like this:

```
int i = getval();
if (i == 4)
{
    i = 10;
}
else if (i == 10)
{
    i = 4;
}
```

My question is there another way to do this without the need to check for each condition.

Comment: I don't know c#, but you could alternate the value of i between 10 and 4 like this:  `i = 7-i`

Comment: *I have a huge list of checks*  Are all your checks of this type? e.g. If its one of these two values swap? Do they all involve the result of `getval()` or is it more complicated?

Comment: Well, that would only with this case. I have another values like 9 and 5. But thanks anyway I guess switch will do the job.

Comment: What about a `Dictionary<int, int>`? So you can write `var i = MyDictionary[getval()];` Only for huge collections of course. Can you tell us what your DataSource is?

Comment: random thought - if you had to get maximum performance (and something like this would probably be in C/C++ or assembly) i wonder if a tricky bit-level algorithm could be devised...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a huge list you might consider some list structure.

```
static Dictionary<int, int> exchange = new Dictionary<int, int>();

static Constructor()
{
    AddExchangePair(4, 10);
    AddExchangePair(3, 12);
    ...
}

static void AddExchangePair(int a, int b)
{
    exchange.Add(a,b);
    exchange.Add(b,a);
}

public staic bool Exchange(ref int value)
{
    int newValue = 0;
    bool exchanged = exchange.TryGetValue(value, out newValue);
    if (exchanged) value = newValue;
    return exchanged;
}
```

This works for huge lists of exchange pairs.

If you call AddExchangePair with a duplicate number e.g. (7,14) and (14, 16) you will get an exception.  You might have to consider what to do in that case.

Comment: You might want to consider moving `value = newValue;` to a new line for readability. +1 tough for considering **huge** collection with a Dictionary.

Comment: Note that for this example you'll need to add both {4,10} and {10,4} to the dictionary.

Comment: Your exchange function is well done. I like that it mimics the call to TryGetValue inside.

Comment: @Casperah, regarding the list structure you refer to - something like a B-Tree?  I wonder if that already exists in a .NET collection somewhere...

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the **[switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** statement.

```
int i = getval();
switch(i)       
      {         
         case 4:   
            i = 10;
            break;                  
         case 10:            
            i = 4;
            break;                 
         default:            
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please select 4 or 10.");            
            break;      
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with using a switch given that you have a "huge list of checks". I would make the checks its own class backed by a Dictionary. This will help minimize the size of your switch statement, and enforce a separation of the checks and the rest of your code:

```
class Cases
{
    private  static readonly Dictionary<int, int>
        List = new Dictionary<int, int>
        {
            {9, 5},
            {3, 2},
            {7, 12},
            {4, 10}
        }; 
    public static int GetCaseValue (int v)
    {
        int result = 0;
        return List.TryGetValue(v, out result) ? result : v;
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        var test = Cases.GetCaseValue(4);
        test = Cases.GetCaseValue(12);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Once you start using object initializers, you'll never go back.

Comment: And using object initializer together with a collection initializer - that is a beauty!

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(i)
{
case 4 : i=10; break;
case 10: i=4; break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't get around some sort of if / switch statement, since there is no easy way to go from 4 to 10 and back. 
If it is 0 and X you swap between, you can go `variable = X - variable;` which swaps it just fine, but for 4 and 10 the above code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i = getval() == 4 ? 10 : 4;
```

That should check if `getval()` is 4 and then toggle between 4 and 10.

Comment: I guess you missed the first sentence  *I have a **huge list** of checks that checks for example...*

Comment: This should still work, no matter how huge the list right? You just put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.

```
int i = getval();
switch (i)
{
    case 4:
    i=10;
    break;
    case 10:
    i=4;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone beat me to this (and wrote it arguable better) but since I wrote the code I'm posting it anyway.

I'll also throw in that the use of `ref` here is probably in both our answers only to maintain compliance with your question and in reality something like this would probably use a functional approach so instead of calling `Swap(ref i)` it would call `i = Swap(i)` and Swap would return it's input if it found no match.  Of course there might be a reason you need to use `ref` - I just can't think of an obvious one off the top of my head.

```
void Main()
{   
    int i;

    i = 1; 
    Swap(ref i); // no swap
    Console.WriteLine (i);

    i = 10; 
    Swap(ref i); // swap with 4
    Console.WriteLine (i);

    i = 4;
    Swap(ref i); // swap with 10
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}

void Swap(ref int i)
{
    if(swaps == null)
    {
        swaps = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        swaps.Add(Tuple.Create(4, 10));
    }

    int compareTo = i;
    var swap1 = from c in swaps where c.Item1 == compareTo select c.Item2;
    var swap2 = from c in swaps where c.Item2 == compareTo select c.Item1;

    if(swap1.Any())
        i = swap1.Single();
    else if(swap2.Any())
        i = swap2.Single();
}

List<Tuple<int, int>> swaps;
```

Output:

```
1
4
10
```